# Как обновить div без перезагрузки страницы

Tags: jquery, ajax

не подскажите есть ли какой метод обновить содержимое без перезагрузки страницы кроме этого
`$("#id").load(location.href + " #id");` Как понимаю он делает перезагрузку всей страницы , а обновляет только данные этого блока. Идёт большая нагрузка на сайт, мб можно как-нибудь обновить конкретно этот блок и в нём число?

Comment: Нет. Метод делает то, что вам нужно. Я не знаю почему вы решили, что он обновляет всю страницу

Comment: Применяю этот метод для обновления цены в корзине , если много товара, то обновления происходит с задержкой в секунд 2-5, не подскажите как это можно оптимизировать? Либо другим способом обновить содержимое блока

Comment: Ну так вы запрос на сервер делайте, который вам вернёт содержимое корзины, а не всей страницы

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сначала создаёте функцию

```
function loadcart(){
     $.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "/include/loadcart.php",
  data: "",
  dataType: "html",
  cache: false,
  success: function(data) {
     
  if (data == "0")
  {
    $(".block-cart > h3").html("Корзина пуста").show();
    
  }else
  {
    $(".block-cart > h3").html(data);
  }      
      }
});          
}
```

Потом при нажатии на .btn_by вызываете функцию

```
 $('.btn_buy').click(function(){
              
 var   tid = $(this).attr("tid");

 $.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "/include/addtocart.php",
  data: "id="+tid,
  dataType: "html",
  cache: false,
  success: function(data) { 
  loadcart();
  loadprice();
      }
});
});
```

Comment: т.е происходит обновление определённого класса

Comment: Спасибо вам большое! Мысль понял, применил - всё работает) В другом направлении мыслил, а всё гениальное просто.